# PHP Just won't display errors

Tags: php

This is frustrating. This code simply won't run, and there are no errors displayed!

As you can see below, I have got an echo at the top of the page, and this doesn't display, however if I remove ALL of the other code apart from the echo, it displays!

I though PHP was procedural, so the echo should display even if there is an error below.

What is going on!?

```
<?php
  echo "test";
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  include 'models/Soccerseason.php';

  class FootballData {
    public $config;
    public $baseUri;
    public $title;
    public $auth = false;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->config = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);
      if($this->config['authToken'] == '4e0aa9dc285343fbb1db8251d64a38c4' || !isset($this->config['authToken'])) {

        $this->baseUri = $this->config['baseUri'];
        $this->reqPrefs['http']['method'] = 'GET';
        $this->reqPrefs['http']['header'] = 'X-Auth-Token: ' . $this->config['authToken'];

        $this->auth = true;
      }
    }

    public function getSoccerseasonById($id) {
      echo "true";
      if ($this->auth == true) {
        $result;
        $resource = 'soccerseasons/' . $id;
        $response = file_get_contents($this->baseUri . $resource, false, stream_context_create());

        if ($response == "" || $response == null)  {
          $response = file_get_contents($this->config['localBackup'] . $resource, false, stream_context_create());
          $result = json_decode($response);
          $response['title'] = 'Local Copy:';
          $result = json_encode($response);
        }
        $result = json_decode($response);

        return new Soccerseason($result);

      } else {
        return array('error' => 'API Key incorrect/not set, please amend in the config.');
      }
    }
  }

  $fixtures = new FootballData->getSoccerseasonById(426);
?>
```

Comment: Shame it gets a -1 due to grammar and the wording I used. Grammar police around. Post was clear, just some extra display of frustration. No contribution to helping solve the issue, just re-wording... -_-

Answer (score 1):

to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:

```
 display_errors = on
```

Comment: I thought the top 3 lines I added would do this though? I can't seem to find anywhere im the cPanel to change these settings.

Comment: @MartynBall: PHP may be set to disallow changing settings via `ini_set()`. And with `display_errors = off` you won't even see a warning that `ini_set()` is disabled.

Comment: cPanel comes with an error log section that allows you to view errors generated by your website

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` won't be run if there is a parse error. And there is - on the last line. It should be: `$fixtures = (new FootballData)->getSoccerseasonById(426);`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enough permissions to change **php.ini**? If yes, you can modify the [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to see if they appear. Try to check the server logs too, the php outputs the errors inside the error logs even if they are disabled on php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Login into your cPanel.
Icon to view cPanel errorsGo to Metrics > Errors. 
[image]

[image]